# why do i keep getting Expected declaration

Tags: iphone, swift

```
@IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    var textField = UITextField()

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add New File", message:"", preferredStyle: .alert)


    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Item", style: .default) { (action) in

        //what will happen after user clicks button
        print(textField.text)
    }
}

alert.addTextField {  (alertTextField) in //where the error begins help

alertTextField.placeholder = "Create New File"

textField = alertTextField



}
present(alert,animated: true,completion:nil)


}
```

Comment: You have an extra `}` directly above `alert.addTextField...`. Is that a copy paste error or does your code have that as well?

Comment: I was trying to edit be fix your code formatting, but the problem might be with the code formatting. Try getting the parentheses matched the way you intend and see if that helps.

Comment: thank you will try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you confused in brackets.
You closed your `IBAction func` after `action` setup.

**Updated code:**

```
@IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    var textField = UITextField()

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add New File", message:"", preferredStyle: .alert)


    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Item", style: .default) { (action) in

        //what will happen after user clicks button
        print(textField.text)
    }

    alert.addTextField {  (alertTextField) in //where the error begins help
        alertTextField.placeholder = "Create New File"

        textField = alertTextField
    }
    present(alert,animated: true,completion:nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra curly braces(before alert.addTextField)

**Your updated Code:**

```
@IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    var textField = UITextField()
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add New File", message:"", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Item", style: .default) { (action) in
        //what will happen after user clicks button
        print(textField.text)
    }

    alert.addTextField {  (alertTextField) in //where the error begins help
        alertTextField.placeholder = "Create New File"
        textField = alertTextField
    }
    present(alert,animated: true,completion:nil)
}
```